# How do I check if a file with a varying path doesn't exist in Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, filepath

I'm attempting to detect if Python is installed on a Windows system at any given time, while future proofing for updates past 3.10 -- though I assume, of course, that this is reproducible with any file or folder that also has a varying path.

### The details

Python doesn't get "installed" the same way others do, i.e. get placed into Program Files (or PF x86) -- it instead gets placed into a user's `AppData\Local\Programs\` folder by default. Since my current project relies on the user having Python installed, I want to make sure when the installer shows up that it completed.

The problem arises with that future proofing I mentioned -- Python 3 folders get named after their version, e.g. the folder containing Python 3.10.2 is in `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\`, 3.9.9 is in `\Python\Python39\`, et cetera. I need to check whether `python.exe` exists or not, but since its directory varies based on version, I also need to check for each folder. However, it occurred to me that there are actually two instances of `python.exe` past the initial `\Python\` folder, one located at the version directory and another deeper in `\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\`.

### The attempts

Currently, I'm attempting to use the method mentioned on [this Microsoft Exchange forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/7ba8dc46-10c5-44c4-90d1-a38db6943d4b/dos-batch-wildcard-in-directory-path?forum=ITCG), which explains the following `FOR` loop could perform a command in each applicable directory;

```
for /r "<folder one>" %a in ("<folder three or file name>") do @if exist %a <command>
```

...which I attempted to apply as a simple check (in a standard cmd process, not in a Batch script) with the following;

```
for /r %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python %A in (python.exe) do @if exist %A echo found %~nxA in %~dpA
```

Because there are multiple matches, though, it returns both paths instead of just the first instance;

```
found python.exe in C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
found python.exe in C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\
```

### The problem

This means I can't simply save `%A` as a variable and check for it, because by `FOR`'s logic it would save the instance at `\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\` and not `\Python310\`, which is the one I'm looking for specifically. I also can't use `if not exist` instead, because if I attempt to do so, `FOR` will act whatever command I use for each of the folders not containing `python.exe`, which would ignore the fact it does exist elsewhere in the tree.

I attempted to save them both as variables by using `/f "tokens=2"`, but after trying to place it both before and after my `/r`, I got errors explaining that either `"tokens=2" was unexpected at this time"` or `"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python" was unexpected at this time"` -- I'm assuming this is due to the fact I can't use multiple options at once, but it isn't mentioned in [`FOR`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for), so I'm not entirely certain.

I also can't simply run `where python.exe`, as it isn't guaranteed Python will be added to PATH since it isn't checked by default when installing.

Comment: I don't use Python, but I expect, `phyton.exe` to be in the PATH. If so, `where phyton.exe` should be helpful. Put a `for /f` around to catch the output.

Comment: Python can potentially end up in PATH, but it's not actually chosen by default in the installer and I can't be 100% certain that someone has chosen for it to be added. I'll add that to the post to clear that up.

Comment: Many developers use Python's `venv` to create separate execution environments for multiple projects. The `python.exe` will not be in the `PATH` until the environment is activated, then removed from the PATH when it is deactivated. There can be several venvs active at a given point in time.

Comment: I would be inclined to just look in the path, with an escape hatch that allows the user to specify the location if it's not in the path or they want to override the behavior.  Otherwise you'll have to hunt for the Windows Store version of Python, the Python.org version, a venv version, and/or a Conda version, in addition to other possibilities.  Even just [finding the python.org version is messy](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/PCbuild/find_python.bat).

Comment: You can't use `for` together with both `/R` and `/F`. However, since `for /R` always returns paths from higher-to-lower-level directories, you could do this: `set "PyPath=" & for /R "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python" %a in (python.exe) do @if exist "%~a" if not defined "PyPath" set "PyPath=%~a"`, so variable `PyPath` is not overwritten with the lower-level match…

Comment: @AnonCoward I don't need to worry about the other various install versions of Python, as if someone's already installed it my batch file is essentially rendered useless (and, furthermore, they likely wouldn't need the assistant my batch file is downloading/installing). My batch file downloads the presumed latest Python installer executable using `curl`, then runs it -- no potential issues over where files are across different ways to install it.

Comment: @aschipfl Deleted my previous comment as I was incorrect with it. It refuses to define `pyver` (which is what I renamed `PyPath` to in my code) using `set`. I set a second `if not defined` up to catch exactly this, and sure enough, my error shows up consistently. I've tried everything I could think of -- changing variable names, moving quotes around, moving where the initial `set "pyver="` is -- all to no avail.